# How to assign variable to buttons in a loop to use those variables on click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, button, variable-assignment

For example at the loop below i want to assign buttons custom variable in order to determine which button clicked on click event with jquery

Here the code :

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < dsProjeler.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
   {
       lblProjeName.Text = string.Format("<a target=\"_blank\" href=\""
           + dsProjeler.Tables[0].Rows[i]["link"].ToString() + "\">{0}</a>",
           dsProjeler.Tables[0].Rows[i]["baslik"].ToString());
%>
<tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Literal ID="lblProjeName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:Button CssClass="sinifKatil" runat="server" Text="Katılmak İstiyorum" OnClick="btnKatil_Click" />
        <asp:Button CssClass="sinifAyril" runat="server" Text="Ayrılmak İstiyorum" OnClick="btnAyril_Click" />
    </td>
</tr>
<% } %>
```

So the real question is assigning custom variables to `<asp:Button` objects in the loop for in order to use those variables at on click event. The variables that can be read.

ASP.net 4.0, C# 4.0, HTML, javascript, Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a Repeater control instead of the scriplet and pass your custom variable to the CommandArgument property of *sinifAyril* and *sinifAyril* buttons. Here is an example how the variable can be retrieved in the click handler

```
 protected void btnKatil_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string value = ((Button) sender).CommandArgument;
      Response.Write(value);
 }
```